# Ignorar determinado valor com AVG

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria que o calculo `AVG` ignorasse os valores acima de `100000` (10 segundos), com a seguinte query:

```
user_id,
COUNT(*) as total,
AVG(`exec_time`) as tempoMedio,
SUM(CASE WHEN `success` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) inTime,
SUM(CASE WHEN `exec_time` <= 0.900 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) above900,
SUM(CASE WHEN `exec_time` <= 3000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) above3000
FROM MYTABLE WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN "DATA 1" AND "DATA 2"
```

A idéia principal é:

Em uma determinada data pegar; o ID do usuario, o tempo médio da coluna `exec_time` ignorando valores acima de `10000`, a quantidade de registros que possuem a coluna `success` como 1, a quantidade de `exec_time` que forem `<= 0.900` e a quantidade de `exec_time <= 3000`

Comment: você falar o valor antes do AVG exec_time ou o resultado dele ?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza o resutado dele, no calculo de média eu não gostaria de incluir valores acima de 10000.

Answer (score 0):

Vendo o seu select acredito que esteja faltando um group by ...

Para fazer o filtro você pode usar a clausula [having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

```
Select
    user_id,
    COUNT(*) as total,
    AVG(`exec_time`) as tempoMedio,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `success` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) inTime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `exec_time` <= 0.900 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) above900,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `exec_time` <= 3000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) above3000
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN "DATA 1" AND "DATA 2"

-- vaja a falta do group by
group by user_id, success, exec_time

-- se for o exec_time
having exec_time <= 10000

-- Ou se for a média
having tempoMedio <= 10000
```